# Returning Rows Created in a Cursor From a Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, cursor, temp-tables

I have a table with three columns each containing comma separated data like

`AAA,BBB,CCC,DDD,...`.

I want to return a `CROSS JOIN` with all the possible combinations of all the tokens from all columns, along with some of the other columns on each row.

I have a Split function which returns the tokens in a table. I pass in each column and get a bunch of rows back.

The best way I have been able to come up with to do this is with a cursor, taking each row one at a time. After doing the CROSS JOIN, I write all the calculated rows to a work/temp table. Once all the rows are processed, I SELECT from the work/temp table to return the calculated rows.

My question: Is there a way to do this without the work/temp table?

The code I have now is:

```
DECLARE cPKG CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR SELECT ID, SEARCH, COUNTY, COMPANY FROM DEV..EXPPKG WITH(NOLOCK)
OPEN cPKG
FETCH NEXT FROM cPKG INTO @ID, @SEARCH, @COUNTY, @COMPANY
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO DEV..PKG_DUMP_WORK
                (ID,
                    PKG_CODE,
                    PRICE,
                    CNTY,
                    CPNY,
                    SRCH,
                    SEARCH,
                    COUNTY,
                    COMPANY,
                    SRCH_COUNT,
                    UPDT_DT,
                    UPDT_BY,
                    UPDT_CMT)
    SELECT PKG.ID,
            PKG.PKG_CODE,
            PKG.PRICE,
            CNTY.VALUE AS CNTY,
            CPNY.VALUE AS CPNY,
            SRCH.VALUE AS SRCH,
            PKG.SEARCH,
            PKG.COUNTY,
            PKG.COMPANY,
            PKG.SRCH_COUNT,
            PKG.UPDT_DT,
            PKG.UPDT_BY,
            PKG.UPDT_CMT
    FROM   (SELECT *
            FROM   DEV..EXPPKG WITH(NOLOCK)
            WHERE  ID = @ID) PKG
            CROSS JOIN DBO.Split(@SEARCH, ',') SRCH -- AAA,BBB,CCC...
            CROSS JOIN DBO.Split(@COUNTY, ',') CNTY -- DDD,EEE,FFF..
            CROSS JOIN DBO.Split(@COMPANY, ',') CPNY -- GGG,HHH,KKK...

    FETCH NEXT FROM cPKG INTO @ID, @SEARCH, @COUNTY, @COMPANY
END
CLOSE cPKG
DEALLOCATE cPKG
```

Some data:

```
    INSERT INTO [EXPPKG] ( PKG_CODE, PRICE, SEARCH, COUNTY, COMPANY, SRCH_COUNT, UPDT_DT, UPDT_BY, UPDT_CMT ) VALUES ( 'A-2', 999, 'CO,ER,FC,HB,ST,TX', 'BX,KG,QN,RI', ',AAN,ALR,CITI,GRANITE,HARB,LLS,LTTA,MADI,NARROW,REGENCY,', 6, NULL, NULL, NULL );
    INSERT INTO [EXPPKG] ( PKG_CODE, PRICE, SEARCH, COUNTY, COMPANY, SRCH_COUNT, UPDT_DT, UPDT_BY, UPDT_CMT ) VALUES ( 'AM-2', 999, 'CO,ER,FC,HB,ST,TX', 'MA', ',ALR,CITI,GRANITE,INTER,LTTA,MADI,SKYLINE,', 6, NULL, NULL, NULL );
    INSERT INTO [EXPPKG] ( PKG_CODE, PRICE, SEARCH, COUNTY, COMPANY, SRCH_COUNT, UPDT_DT, UPDT_BY, UPDT_CMT ) VALUES ( 'B-2', 999, 'AR,CO,ER,FC,HB,HI,HL,ST,TX', 'BX,KG,QN,RI', ',C&C,LTTA,', 9, NULL, NULL, NULL );
    INSERT INTO [EXPPKG] ( PKG_CODE, PRICE, SEARCH, COUNTY, COMPANY, SRCH_COUNT, UPDT_DT, UPDT_BY, UPDT_CMT ) VALUES ( 'CA-2', 999, 'CO,ER,FC,HB,HI,ST,TX', 'BX,KG,MA,QN,RI', ',CANY,CHATHAM,TRAK,', 7, NULL, NULL, NULL );
    INSERT INTO [EXPPKG] ( PKG_CODE, PRICE, SEARCH, COUNTY, COMPANY, SRCH_COUNT, UPDT_DT, UPDT_BY, UPDT_CMT ) VALUES ( 'CT-4', 999, 'CO,ER,FC,HB', 'BX,KG,MA,QN,RI', ',CLTLTNY,CTALB,CTIM,CTIM-711,CTIM-CC,CTIM-Q,CTIM-R,CTIMR-O,FNT,FNT-A,FNT-AG,FNT-N,FNT-R,NYLS,TICOR,TICORROC,FNT-RAM,', 4, NULL, NULL, NULL );
```

Comment: Why are you using a cursor for this? There is no need for a cursor here at all. This should be a single insert statement. And what does your Split function have? More looping? Delimited data is bad design as it violates 1NF. And those NOLOCK hints are far more sinister than most people realize too.

Comment: SL: I didn't design the data and it cannot be changed. The columns contain comma delimited data like AAA,BBB,CCC.. Each row contains three such columns. Columns may contain 1-N tokens- cannot be predicted. SPLIT takes a column and turns it into one row per delimited token so they can be CROSSed. If you have a way to do this in a single pass, I'd like to hear it.

Comment: I believe CROSS APPLY is the answer, but the database compatibility is ancient. Switched to a new database and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could replace the entire cursor with a set based insert. I would also caution you against using that NOLOCK hint. It can and will return missing and/or duplicate rows. Along with a number of other nasty things. http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

```
INSERT INTO DEV..PKG_DUMP_WORK
(
    ID,
    PKG_CODE,
    PRICE,
    CNTY,
    CPNY,
    SRCH,
    SEARCH,
    COUNTY,
    COMPANY,
    SRCH_COUNT,
    UPDT_DT,
    UPDT_BY,
    UPDT_CMT
)
SELECT PKG.ID,
    PKG.PKG_CODE,
    PKG.PRICE,
    CNTY.VALUE AS CNTY,
    CPNY.VALUE AS CPNY,
    SRCH.VALUE AS SRCH,
    PKG.SEARCH,
    PKG.COUNTY,
    PKG.COMPANY,
    PKG.SRCH_COUNT,
    PKG.UPDT_DT,
    PKG.UPDT_BY,
    PKG.UPDT_CMT
FROM   DEV..EXPPKG PKG WITH(NOLOCK)
CROSS APPLY DBO.Split(PKG.SEARCH, ',') SRCH -- AAA,BBB,CCC...
CROSS APPLY DBO.Split(PKG.COUNTY, ',') CNTY -- DDD,EEE,FFF..
CROSS APPLY DBO.Split(PKG.COMPANY, ',') CPNY -- GGG,HHH,KKK...
```

Comment: CROSS APPLY is the secret, I think. Unfortunately, CROSS APPLY doesn't seem to like that qualified column as a parameter to Split. It barfs on the period.

Comment: What does "barfs on the period" mean? I assume that you get an error message? Sharing that error message would help us understand the problem considerably.

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 101
Incorrect syntax near '.'.

Comment: What version of sql server are you using? Or what is the compatibility mode set to? I have a feeling you are running sql 2000 or in 2000 compatibility mode.

Comment: I'm wondering if this is a databse version issue: "SEARCH" is not a recognized table hints option. If it is intended as a parameter to a table-valued function or to the CHANGETABLE function, ensure that your database compatibility mode is set to 90.

Comment: 2000. I moved it to a "modern" instance and it started working.

Comment: APPLY and inline table valued functions were not available until 2005. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [CROSS APPLY](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx)

```
SELECT *
FROM   DEV..EXPPKG WITH(NOLOCK)
CROSS APPLY DBO.Split(SEARCH, ',') SRCH -- AAA,BBB,CCC...
CROSS APPLY DBO.Split(COUNTY, ',') CNTY -- DDD,EEE,FFF..
CROSS APPLY DBO.Split(COMPANY, ',') CPNY
```

This is the solution using a generic Split function

```
DROP FUNCTION SplitString
GO
CREATE FUNCTION SplitString
(    
      @Input NVARCHAR(MAX),
      @Character CHAR(1)
)
RETURNS @Output TABLE (
      Value NVARCHAR(1000)
)
AS
BEGIN
      DECLARE @StartIndex INT, @EndIndex INT
      SET @StartIndex = 1
      IF SUBSTRING(@Input, LEN(@Input) - 1, LEN(@Input)) <> @Character
      BEGIN
            SET @Input = @Input + @Character
      END

      WHILE CHARINDEX(@Character, @Input) > 0
      BEGIN
            SET @EndIndex = CHARINDEX(@Character, @Input)

            INSERT INTO @Output(Value)
            SELECT SUBSTRING(@Input, @StartIndex, @EndIndex - 1)

            SET @Input = SUBSTRING(@Input, @EndIndex + 1, LEN(@Input))
      END

      RETURN
END
GO

    declare @EXPPKG table ( ID int identity,  PKG_CODE varchar(5) , PRICE int , SEARCH varchar(255), COUNTY varchar(255), COMPANY varchar(255), SRCH_COUNT varchar(255), UPDT_DT varchar(255), UPDT_BY varchar(255), UPDT_CMT varchar(255))
    INSERT INTO @EXPPKG  ( PKG_CODE, PRICE, SEARCH, COUNTY, COMPANY, SRCH_COUNT, UPDT_DT, UPDT_BY, UPDT_CMT ) VALUES ( 'A-2', 999, 'CO,ER,FC,HB,ST,TX', 'BX,KG,QN,RI', ',AAN,ALR,CITI,GRANITE,HARB,LLS,LTTA,MADI,NARROW,REGENCY,', 6, NULL, NULL, NULL );
    INSERT INTO @EXPPKG  ( PKG_CODE, PRICE, SEARCH, COUNTY, COMPANY, SRCH_COUNT, UPDT_DT, UPDT_BY, UPDT_CMT ) VALUES ( 'AM-2', 999, 'CO,ER,FC,HB,ST,TX', 'MA', ',ALR,CITI,GRANITE,INTER,LTTA,MADI,SKYLINE,', 6, NULL, NULL, NULL );
    INSERT INTO @EXPPKG  ( PKG_CODE, PRICE, SEARCH, COUNTY, COMPANY, SRCH_COUNT, UPDT_DT, UPDT_BY, UPDT_CMT ) VALUES ( 'B-2', 999, 'AR,CO,ER,FC,HB,HI,HL,ST,TX', 'BX,KG,QN,RI', ',C&C,LTTA,', 9, NULL, NULL, NULL );
    INSERT INTO @EXPPKG  ( PKG_CODE, PRICE, SEARCH, COUNTY, COMPANY, SRCH_COUNT, UPDT_DT, UPDT_BY, UPDT_CMT ) VALUES ( 'CA-2', 999, 'CO,ER,FC,HB,HI,ST,TX', 'BX,KG,MA,QN,RI', ',CANY,CHATHAM,TRAK,', 7, NULL, NULL, NULL );
    INSERT INTO @EXPPKG  ( PKG_CODE, PRICE, SEARCH, COUNTY, COMPANY, SRCH_COUNT, UPDT_DT, UPDT_BY, UPDT_CMT ) VALUES ( 'CT-4', 999, 'CO,ER,FC,HB', 'BX,KG,MA,QN,RI', ',CLTLTNY,CTALB,CTIM,CTIM-711,CTIM-CC,CTIM-Q,CTIM-R,CTIMR-O,FNT,FNT-A,FNT-AG,FNT-N,FNT-R,NYLS,TICOR,TICORROC,FNT-RAM,', 4, NULL, NULL, NULL );
```

Select

```
    select 
            PKG.ID,
            PKG.PKG_CODE,
            PKG.PRICE,
            SRCH.Value AS CNTY,
            CPNY.Value CPNY,
            SRCH.Value AS SRCH,
            PKG.SEARCH,
            PKG.COUNTY,
            PKG.COMPANY,
            PKG.SRCH_COUNT,
            PKG.UPDT_DT,
            PKG.UPDT_BY,
            PKG.UPDT_CMT
             from @EXPPKG PKG
             CROSS APPLY DBO.SplitString(SEARCH, ',') SRCH 
             CROSS APPLY DBO.SplitString(COUNTY, ',') CNTY 
             CROSS APPLY DBO.SplitString(COMPANY, ',') CPNY
```

Result
[image]

Comment: SEARCH, COUNTY, and COMPANY are columns in DEV..EXPPKG. This fails because SQL doesn't recognize them as such. I believe this is heading in the right direction, but I haven't managed to crack the code to get it to work.

Comment: Please add some data exemple and the function. I need to reproduce the environment to help you.

Comment: Data added to main question text.

Comment: Check the function's output table name. I added a complete code using your data and a generic Split function.

Comment: Copied verbatim, even using your function: Msg 321, Level 15, State 1, Line 140
"SEARCH" is not a recognized table hints option. If it is intended as a parameter to a table-valued function or to the CHANGETABLE function, ensure that your database compatibility mode is set to 90. This database is ancient. Might be the problem.

Comment: I would urge you to throw that splitter away and start using a set based one instead. My favorite is Jeff Moden's. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/ There are several other excellent alternatives here. https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings